# DNS, Google Cloud and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I bought a domain from Godaddy and changed the nameservers correctly. Connected to my google cloud hosting. everything was done properly. I installed WordPress as well. But my site is not working. It is a fresh domain purchased 30 mins before the deployment. Is it because of DNS change or what?
When my site and my Wordpress dashboard will be live?

Comment: Check your DNS settings and could you tell me if you've updated your MX records? If you've not then your site may not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The dns record propagation can take up to 48 hours. [What factors affect DNS propagation time? (GoDaddy)](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time-1746)